# Selective showing of checkboxes in treeview (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

(This is not WPF)

Is there a way to hide checkboxes on a parent node in a treeview (this is in fact a directory) - I am guessing it's an all or nothing thing though - either you have checkboxes for everything or nothing.  I say this as the treeview control has a property CheckBoxes = true/false - "indicates whether check boxes are displayed by nodes".

Just thought I would check though.

BTW - has anyone used this treeview control - is it reliable, any good? [TreeVeiwAdv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed no support for such functionality. There is workaround however, by using p/invoke on the win32 API and send a TVM_SETITEM message.

See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/msg/69a62ef36dcd8eb8) for an example by Jeffrey Tan.

Comment: Well it was never going to be elegant but it does the job!  Thanks for the help.